# google play service attribute has already been defined

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin, android-gridlayout

I'm new user in android studio.i added lates google play service in my project and i have log error

> Error:(2) Attribute "orientation" has already been defined

[this is a image in my log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7HW8.png)

[also this is a my dependencies 's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0aTf.png)

as you can see gridlayout has red line.i use compileSdk Version API:22 and Build Tools Version 22.0.0
how i can solve my problme? if anyone knows solution please help me thanks everyone

Comment: check if you have specified `orientation` attribute in any of the layouts..could you please post the xml file too..

Comment: @Lal whitch xml do you mean ??

Comment: I think there is contradiction happening in using the play service , I think the specific attribute is being duplicate/replicated , Can you tell me what are you using in your app, Map, Any thing like that ?

Comment: yes sir maps and push notification.but when i use gridlayout and play-service together i have error.meybe problem is gridlayout @Lal

Comment: Check out this thread.. Might resolve your issue.. https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout/issues/29